# Matlab Graphing in 4D with Symbolic Variables

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

I have the following equations:

```
FindBurrow = .3*log(x+2)-.2
DistEffect= normpdf(y,0,6) + 0.92
VegEffect = -.006*z+1
Detection = FindBurrow*DistEffect*VegEffect
```

I would like to visualize the Detection function as part of a 4-D visualization. The fourth dimension would be color to represent Detection. I see that it is possible to do this if I have matrices with real x,y,z values but I currently don't.

I have tried to convert my symbolic x,y,z values to real 100 by 100 matrices using the following but it doesn't seem to work properly.

```
%% Conversion to "Real" Numbers
syms f(x,y,z)
f(x,y,z) = Detection;
[x,y] = ndgrid(linspace(1/10,50), linspace(1/10, 50))
z] = ndgrid(linspace(1/10,50), linspace(1/10, 50))
g = matlabFunction(Detection);
DetKernel = real(g(x,y,z)) 
%% Graphing the IPM
figure
surf(x,y,z,DetKernel) % surface map
clear title xlabel ylabel %Clears old runs index
xlabel ('Burrow Size') %x-axis label
ylabel('Distance From Line') %y-axis label
zlabel('Vegetation Effect') %z-axis label
cb = colorbar;
cb.Label.String = 'Probability of Detection';
```

I suspect this is due to a lack of knowledge of how to define the x,y,z values to make them act like grid points that Matlab will then use to make a surface or mesh. The graphing part seems to work okay, just doesn't make the shape I would expect based on experimental plotting of the X*Y, Y*Z, Z*X equations.

In short I have two questions: 1. Can I graph 4D using symbolic variables? 2. If not, how do I convert to real numbers without messing up my data?

For reference, x will be between 0 and 55, y will be between 0 and 25 and z will be between 0 and 160.

Comment: It would be helpful if you add the plot that you get and some example for what is not right, based on your expectation. Right now I'm getting [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXC1k.png) with your code, and have no clue what's wrong with it.

Comment: Apologies for that. This is quite embarrassing but what I realized was happening was that the x/y/z variables were being put on the graph in a different order than I was expecting (i.e. FindBurrows was originally defined with symbolic variable x but was not put on the x axis in the final). Once that got worked out, I got the type of graph I was expecting. Sorry for wasting your time!